# When I type "nano ~/.zshrc" in terminal, I get a weird PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, path

So I downloaded anaconda a while back, and I deleted it. But when I go to type in "nano ~/.zshrc" I get some shell code:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /$
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Also when I type in "echo $PATH" I get:

```
/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Now i know a little about PATH, but not enough to know what any of this is (pretty much a script kiddie), so is this normal to have after you've deleted an app? I though PATH was a directory with a bunch of bins, so what is all this?

Note: Everything works fine in my computer, but i'm pretty sketehced from all of this, if you could shed some light here I'd highly appreciate it

Comment: Looks like you can safely remove these lines if you are not using Anaconda. The installer seems to add things to users' startup files and then forget that it did that.

Comment: @BuddyPal : I find it already creepy if an installer secretly modifies my own `.zshrc`, but of course the uninstaller can not know whether you have in the meantime tailored your .zshrc to your taste, so at least you should be grateful that the anaconda uninstaller did NOT try to fix your .zshrc and maybe ruin it even more. Basically this file is yours and you can do with it whatever you like, and any sane installer should keep its fingers away from it.